# How to get marker drag event on dragging marker with mapbox LeafLet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, mapbox

I have created custom create Marker button and onClick of that i am adding marker on map.

I can drag that map but I am lot getting it's LatLng on dragging.
I want to get latlng on marker drag event.Below is my code for creating marker.

```
this.map.on('draw:created', function(e) {
        e.layer.options.draggable = true;
        this.drawnItems.addLayer(e.layer);
        this.props.markerCoordinates(e.layer._latlng);
        this.mapState = MAP_STATE.NONE;
        mapSearch.searchByLocation(e.layer._latlng, this.getLocation);
        this.setState({
            drawActiveClass: 'polygonAction clearfix',
        });
    }.bind(this));

    drawMarker: function() {
    if(this.mapState === MAP_STATE.DRAW) {
        return;
    }
    this.drawnItems.clearLayers();
    this.mapState = MAP_STATE.DRAW;
    this.drawHandler = new L.Draw.Marker(this.map,this.drawControl.options.draw.marker);
    this.drawHandler.enable();
    this.setState({
        drawActiveClass: 'polygonAction clearfix active',
        createMarkerErrorClass: 'hide'
    });
}

render: function() {
     <li className={this.state.drawActiveClass} ref="drawMarker" onClick={this.drawMarker}>
          <span className="drawAction">{this.props.drawAction}</span>
     </li>
}
```

On marker create I am making it draggable. 
But how to add drag event for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just added dragend event listner inside created event.

```
  this.map.on('draw:created', function(e) {
        e.layer.options.draggable = true;
        e.layer.on('dragend',function(e) {
            mapSearch.searchByLocation(e.target.getLatLng(),this.getLocation);
        }.bind(this));
        this.drawnItems.addLayer(e.layer);
        this.props.markerCoordinates(e.layer._latlng);
        this.mapState = MAP_STATE.NONE;
        mapSearch.searchByLocation(e.layer._latlng, this.getLocation);
        this.setState({
            drawActiveClass: 'polygonAction clearfix',
        });
    }.bind(this));
```